# Regular expression to validate the user input

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want a regular expression, which should start with alphabet or numbers and followed by alphanumeric character and in between, it may or may not contain forward or backward slash (`\,/`).

Highly appreciate your help.

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is your current code failing?

Comment: My reguler expression expecting / and \ as input. And i'm new to this reguler expression. Please help me with this.

Comment: **Regular** - not *reguler* ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^[a-z0-9][\w\\\/]+$/i
```

1. Start of line (`^`).
2. `[a-z0-9]` - a letter or number - 1 occurrence
3. `[\w\\\/]+` - multiple occurrences of alphanumeric characters (including `_`) or `\` or `/`.
4. Line end (`$`).

`i`gnore-case flag will accept both uppercase and lowercase.

`[xyz]` specifies a character class meaning that either `x` or `y` or `z` can be matched.

#### [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hB2bW7)

If you don't consider `123_asd` to be alpha-numeric, use:

```
/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\\\/]+$/i
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\/\\]*
```

This will accept / or \ only in between.

Edit: Oops:p Missed the numbers, updated. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This will not accept number at start example 1a will fail. Use ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9\\\/]*

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?i)^[a-z\d][a-z\d\\/]*$
```

`?i` treats upper-case letters as lower-case letters.